# FET transistor for output channel for arduino not working

Tags: transistors, mosfet

I'm trying to work with IRF640 FET transistor (picture attached). [image: FET transistor picture]

The problem is when I put 11V on the G-S voltage. The D-S voltage is 4-6 volts or more.

Why the transistor doesn't open fully?

In the simulator, the voltage falls to 120.18mV.(as expected)

[image: the schematics attached.]Thank you.

Comment: Can you put an ammeter and measure the drain current too? Did you actually measure the \$V_{GS }\$ ? Did you check the gate-source continuity? (if it's not an open: dead MOSFET).

Comment: in real life its: 1.3A from load to drain. Vgs - 10.8V. Vds - 4.5 volts and going up as the transistor getting hotter. tested with 2 mosfet and the results are the same

Comment: Are you following exactly the schematics (i.e. you switch the ground. The source is connected to the ground)? To be sure: aren't you trying to use it as a high-side switch? (i.e. you aren't switching the 12V, right?)

Comment: The problem might be with the diode. Have you checked if it's connected like the way shown in your circuit?

Comment: @dirac16 I was also suspecting the diode (e.g. mounted with A and K reversed), but it would be red-hot by now (unless it is a very big one, mounted in a big heatsink).

Comment: I removed the diode and left only the resistor, the result are the same.

Comment: What's the maximum output current that your power supply can source?

Comment: I limited it on 3A